# How can I bring usernames and passwords from text file and use in C programming language?

Tags: c, database, text

beginI am developing a library system with C. I want to get the username and password from the text file, but I couldn't figure it out. My codes are not in English, but if you can still help I would appreciate it. Thank you.

I hope you can understand the problem...

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int GirisYap() {
    char k_adi[25];
    char sifre[25];
    
    printf("Kullanici adinizi giriniz : ");
    scanf("%s",k_adi);
    printf("Sifrenizi giriniz : ");
    scanf("%s",sifre);

    FILE* fFile = fopen("hesaplardatabase.txt", "r");

    if(fFile == NULL) {
        printf("Böyle bir dosya bulunamadı.");
        return 0;
    }

    int i, kkontrol, skontroldevam;
    char sBuffer[256], sKullaniciAdi[32], sSifre[32];
    char *sArrayKullaniciAdi[64];
    char *sArraySifre[64];
    int tokeni, ki, si, x;

    char *array[256];
    for(i = 1; fgets(sBuffer, sizeof(sBuffer), fFile) != NULL; i++) {
        char *token = strtok(sBuffer, "-");

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            array[x++] = token;
            token = strtok (NULL, "-");
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        printf("%s\n", array[x]);
    }
        
        /*
        

        while(token != NULL) {
            if(tokeni % 2 == 0) {
                sArrayKullaniciAdi[ki] = token;
                ki++;
            }
            else {
                sArraySifre[si] = token;
                si++;
            }

            tokeni++;
            token = strtok (NULL, "-");
        }
        */


        /*
        strtok(sBuffer, sKullaniciAdi, sizeof(sKullaniciAdi), sSifre, sizeof(sSifre));
        printf("%s %s", sKullaniciAdi, sSifre);
    //strbreak bosluktan sonrasını ayırıyor
        if(strcmp(sKullaniciAdi, k_adi) == 0 && strcmp(sSifre, sifre) == 0) {
            printf("\n\nSifreniz dogru.\nBasariyla giris yapildi\nLutfen Bekleyiniz...");
            fclose(fFile);
            return 1;
        }
        */

    fclose(fFile);
    return 0;
}
```

`

The problem is that, I bring datas but I can not use them as a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION IS HERE :

```
int GirisYap() {

char k_adi[25];
char sifre[25];

printf("Kullanici adinizi giriniz : ");
scanf("%s",k_adi);
printf("Sifrenizi giriniz : ");
scanf("%s",sifre);

FILE *passwords = fopen("sifre.txt", "r");
FILE *usernames = fopen("kadi.txt", "r");

if (usernames == NULL || passwords == NULL) {
    return 0;
}

char username[256], password[256];

int giris = 0;

while(1) {
    if(!fgets(username, sizeof(username), usernames)) {
        break;
    }

    if(!fgets(password, sizeof(password), passwords)) {
        break;
    }

    username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = 0;
    password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;

    if(strcmp(username, k_adi) == 0 && strcmp(password, sifre) == 0) {
        giris = 1;
        break;
    }
}

fclose(usernames);
fclose(passwords);

if(giris == 1) {
    return 1;
}

return 0;
```

}